# Issue with for-loop in render method(Libgdx)

Tags: java, for-loop, libgdx

In my `render()` method in libgdx, I have this loop, which iterates through an array of enemies and checks if the player has collided with them. If so, the screen switches to a game over screen, where the player can restart the game.

```
for(Enemy x: enemies){
    if(x.bounds.overlaps(player.bounds)){
        game.setScreen(game.gameOver);
    }
}
```

My issue is that the enemies remain in the position they were when the player collided with one of them, although the player has restarted the game, and a `reset()` method has run. Visually, everything is reset as well - it's just the collision detection finding enemies not where they are displayed now, but rather where they were before restarting.

If I remove my for loop, and write an if statement for every individual enemy, it works.

```
if(player.bounds.overlaps(enemy1.bounds)){
    game.setScreen(game.gameOver);
}
```

Kinda new to programming. If someone could help, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: can you add the complete `render()` method?

Comment: Did you find an answer? I have similiar problem with for loop inside render method..

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `break` to your cycle if you detect a collision:

```
for(Enemy x: enemies){
    if(x.bounds.overlaps(player.bounds)){
        game.setScreen(game.gameOver);
        break;
    }
}
```

That will prevent calling `game.setScreen(game.gameOver);` multiple times if more enemies collide with the player at the same time.

Comment: I did, but the issue remains.